# SQL Azure Firewall Rules on New Portal (2014)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Another year and another Azure portal redesign. I'm now running in the new Preview and I cannot find where to allow a firewall rule so that outside IP addresses (Visual Studio on my own machine) can access Azure SQL.

Does anyone know where this can be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here's the journey: Click Browse, select SQL databases, select your database, now in the database blade click on the server (not the database), you'll now see the server blade where you can click on the Firewall settings.  Voilà!